# Aggregate chosen observations in one data frame and transfer them to another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to programming and R, and I have tried to find the answer to this question, but I didn't succeed. I think I need some nested for loops, but I simply can't wrap my head around this problem.

I have two data frames. The first contains client information such as name, age, address and so on. These clients all have a unique client.no. 
In the other data frame I have information about the insurance policies the clients have (about six times as many entries as the client_info df). In this data frame there is a unique policy.no for each row, and the client.no is also stated, but here there is obviously more than one row with the same client.no.

```
client.no <- c(1:10)
num.policy <- 0
client_info <- data.frame(client.no, num.policy)
policy.no <- c(1:100)
set.seed(1)
policy_info <- data.frame(policy.no, client.no = sample(client.no, 100, replace=TRUE))
```

I want to transfer the information about the policies to the first data frame with the client information. How do I count the number of policies for each client and then transfer this number to a new variable in the client information data frame?

What I need is the variable `client_info$num_policy` to contain the number of policies the individual clients have. I do not care, when this variable is made (I just show it here as an example)

This is not the only task I need to do, as example I also need to summarize the price of the different policies, and then transfer that to the `client_info` dataframe. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aggregate` to count number of policies by customer and then `merge` to put that information back into your original dataframe:

```
> merge(client_info, aggregate(policy.no ~ client.no, data = policy_info, FUN=length))
   client.no num.policy policy.no
1          1          0         7
2          2          0         6
3          3          0        11
4          4          0        14
5          5          0        14
6          6          0         5
7          7          0        11
8          8          0        15
9          9          0        11
10        10          0         6
```

The `aggregate` part alone may even be what you're looking for. You can change the `FUN` argument to do different things (sounds like you may want `mean` or `sum` for some of your other needs).